# Find the number of possible combinations for a combination lock if each combination...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Question: Find the number of possible combinations for a combination lock if each combination consists of three integers, not necessarily distinct, from 0 to 39. 
(Warning: The term “combination” will take on a special mathematical meaning in the next section. Do not confuse the ordinary use in this problem with that meaning.)

What does "not necessarily distinct" mean anyway? 
If distinct: $(40)(39)(38)$?

Not distinct: $(40)^3$?

I'm not sure what to do nor explain my reasoning. Please help!

Comment: Not distinct: 40 is not distinct from 40, but distinct from 39. Not different, in simpler words.

Comment: Also in your case a combination like 40, 39,40 is also allowed

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Not necessarily distinct" means that numbers can be repeated.  Your answer of $40^3$ is correct if combinations have not yet been defined as it appears.  Combinations will be defined as not caring about order, so 1,2,3 is the same as 3,1,2.  It would be strange, but a well defined problem, to allow duplicates but not care about order.